# iPhone slide animation when view is loaded

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

How to perform a sliding animation when a view is being loaded in an iPhone application?

I have a ViewController in which I have subview. I want that the subview be loaded with an animation, sliding from the left to the right.

I got this code so far:

```
-(void) showAnimation{

    [self.view addSubview:geopointView]
    geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(20,150,550,200)// somewhere offscreen, in the direction you want it to appear from
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
         animations:^{
             geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(20,150,550,200)// its final location
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not?

```
-(void) showAnimation{
[self.view addSubview:geopointView]
geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(-200,150,550,200)// just set a different frame
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
             delay:0.0
             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                 geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(20,150,550,200)// its final location
             }
             completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: in first fram what to give the exaxt location  of the frame to show on screen or any thing else

Comment: the first frame means the animation's start location of the view, as you wish , it should located on the left of the screen, in or out of it

Comment: ok thanks i got this working but can you tell me when this view is loaded then on another button click i want this view should be hidden and agian relaoded on button click

Comment: i don't quite understand..  should animated again?

Comment: thanks again got the solution after playing with code thanks alot